# How do I update a list in real time using rxjava?

Tags: android, rx-java

A recyclerview is filled with data from a web service.  I want the recyclerview to update whenever the web service changes the data without any user interaction.  Is there a better way to do this using rxjava besides making a polling request every X milliseconds?  Is there an rx construct that always listens to changes?

Comment: How are you pulling data from webservice ? Are you polling and want to remove that too ?

Comment: yes I could poll (call the web service every X ms) but that would be taxing.  The service gives me the list of data.

Comment: This is more an architecture design question, more than technical. You can have polling or publisher subscriber design. In the second one is your web service the one that have to publish in some observable and you being subscribed. But since this multi layer, I can only think in  use of Kafka or another broker where you can subscribe.

Comment: Otherwise to do polling in rxjava you can use interval https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/creating/ObservableInterval.java

Comment: thank you paul.  My web service returns an observable but it only returns once for the current state of data.  I would like the observable to emit  
whenever the list of data changes.  This would prevent me from polling the service and seeing that the data is the same